# Directive isolated scope two-way data binding results in "undefined"

Tags: angularjs

I am referring to a directive from a view (part of a route component). The directive is configured with isolated scope and a two-way data binding.

Route Component View:

```
<audit-directive  audit-id="pageAudit.selectedAuditId"></audit-directive>
```

Route component controller:

```
angular.module('components.pageAudit', ['components.sections.audit', 'components.sections.audit.directive'])
.controller('PageAuditController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $routeParams) {


    console.log("*** PageAuditController with $routeParams => "+ JSON.stringify($routeParams, null, 4));

    var vm = this;
    vm.selectedAuditId = $routeParams.id;
    console.log('Selected audit id at PageAuditController=> '+vm.selectedAuditId);
}]);
```

Directive definition:

```
angular.module('components.sections.audit.directive', [])
.directive('auditDirective', auditDirective);

function auditDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope : {
            auditId : '='
        },
        controller: 'AuditController',
        controllerAs: 'audit',
        template: '<div ng-include="components/audit/audit.html" layout-fill></div>'
    };
}
```

Directive Controller:

```
angular.module('components.sections.audit', [])
    .controller('AuditController', ['AuditManagementService','$scope', '$timeout', '$location', '$routeParams', function (AuditManagementService, $scope, $timeout, $location, $routeParams) {
        console.log("*****************Audit Controller");


        $scope.audit = {};

        console.log("Selected Audit Id at AuditController=> "+ $scope.auditId);

    }]);
```

When the directive gets instantiated, the value of $scope.auditId at the directive controller (AuditController) is logged as undefined even when though a valid value is being passed from the parent view. I have logged the value in parent controller and it logs the value.

So, the log looks like below..

```
*** PageAuditController with $routeParams => {
    "id": "2"
}
page-audit.js:11 Selected audit id at PageAuditController=> 2
audit.js:5 *****************Audit Controller
audit.js:52 Selected Audit Id at AuditController=> undefined
```

I am trying to find out why the directive controller would interpret the value as undefined?

Note: When I tried to inspect the scope using Batarang in chrome, I see auditId property has a value 2. So, may be, it's not yet populated when I attempt to log using console.log and is populated only at a later point?

Comment: What version of `angularjs` are you using?

Comment: I am using angularjs 1.4.8.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct, bindings are initialized a bit later. IN `angularjs` v1.5+ you can use [`$onInit()` lifecycle hook on `directive` controller to do initialization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Adding this `ng-if="pageAudit.selectedAuditId"` to the html while referring to the directive seems to work better.